# Premade APK template for bundling static html website on Android?

Tags: android, webview, apk

I have a 3MB website that's static HTML/CSS/JS and I'd like to package it up into an Android app for offline use.

Are there premade APK archives for static webapps... the kind where I can just insert the static html/css/js and the app is programmed to load "index.html" or something? Presumablty I'd need to put index.html in /res/raw or /assets. I'm not a Java programmer so that's that main reason I'm asking.

I understand that APK files need to be cryptographically signed but presumably I can do this later.

Answer (score 1):

[AppMobi](http://www.appmobi.com/) takes your webapp, compiles it with their pre-built template, and gives you the resulting APK. Make sure you use a custom loading splash image and implement the hack workaround in the forums to speed up first-time loading.

You don't need to do anything but create a new project and paste your web-app into the project folder, then follow the screenshots. [And that hack I mentioned.](http://forums.appmobi.com/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=431&sid=d8c7b49817f44854ef0661744b077c43)

If you have or understand gradle, I did this to prevent polluting the actual web-app:

```
task appmobi(dependsOn: [buildForWeb]) << {
    File indexFile = new File('build/index.html')

    def appMobiLoader = '''<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:58888/_appMobi/appmobi.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function deviceReadyListener() {
    AppMobi.device.hideSplashScreen();
}
window.document.addEventListener("appMobi.device.ready", deviceReadyListener, false);
</script>'''

    def indexText = indexFile.text.replace("</head>", "$appMobiLoader</head>")
    indexFile.withWriter { writer ->
        writer.write(indexText)
    }
}
```

Comment: There is unfortunately something else now under that AppMobi link... Is there any other solution, potentially a pipeline based one?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the PhoneGap project. http://www.phonegap.com/